# Scripts Not Working in Content Editor

Tags: content-editor-web-part, script, script-editor-webpart

I have a generic out of box web part page.  I have added a content editor web part on that page that links to a HTML file because I want to build my own custom form via HTML.

Here is the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .field{
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    .field label{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 160px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .field select{
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ItemTypeSelect").append(new Option('test', 'test'));
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Item Type:</label>
        <select id="ItemTypeSelect" name="ItemType"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Manufacturer:</label>
        <select name="Manufacturer"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Model:</label>
        <select name="Model"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Serial Number(s):</label>
        <select multiple='multiple' name="SerialNumber"></select>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

On page load, my scripts are not working, and I'm not receiving any runtime errors in the console.  I have also tried adding a script editor to my page and put the scripts that you see above in the script editor and they are still not working without any errors in console.

How do I get scripts to work in an HTML file or script editor for a form inside a content editor?

Comment: Try adding breakpoint inside document.ready() and debug. See if gets the select element properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `type` attribute to your `script` tag, like given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.log('In.');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case this helps anyone I also had to call use .js extension instead of .html on the linked file to get the scripts to load

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).